# MATLAB class in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, matlab-deployment

I have some custom classes in MATLAB and I want to use them in my C# project. I read a little bit and used `deploytool` to generate `dll` files. Sadly, its not working as I expect it to work. The classes are exported as methods and I cant access properties.

I read [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/answers/23086-matlab-classes-in-shared-dll-s) and it says you cant export MATLAB class to C/C++ ( I assume not as a .NET assembly either). Is there a way around it?

I have huge amount of code in MATLAB, and its best if I use it directly than re-writing in C#.

Comment: thanks for comment, its only a basic function that is exported. I need a class to be exported.

Comment: did you figure out the solution?

Comment: there is no solution. Matlab cant export classes, it only exports functions. I decided to code the classes in C# finally.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a Matlab to .net porting utility  see here :

http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/